# Use Sentry Releases in a yarn monorepo

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, sentry, source-maps, monorepo

I'm using a Yarn monorepo which contains Typescript modules that provide content to the backend. I'm using a Github Action workflow for each module to deploy it. In the shared SDK is Sentry configured to catch all errors across those modules. I've read some of Sentry's docs and I tried to upload sourcemaps to Sentry by creating a Release. This way I could get proper stacktraces of the original code.

However, it seems Sentry considers a release valid for the whole codebase, while the source code and sourcemaps of only one module is included. I'm wondering if it's possible to let Sentry assign an Issue to the respective Release. As for now, the most recent release is chosen for each issue, so it happens an Issue is thrown in one module, and Sentry assigns that to the most recent release, which isn't necessarily the release of that module.

In short:
I'm searching a way to let Sentry organize a release not by release date, but by the respective module of the Release's uploaded source code. Sentry should assign Issues to a Release according to it's path to the source code.

[*Infographic: Sentry organizes releases as shown at the left, it stacks them and the upper is the latest. The right graph represents how I want it, for each module a different release 'stack'.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myl2C.png)